# What is the proper way to track my build versions in Qt?

Tags: c++, version-control, builds, qt, metadata

Basically what I need in my project is a number of some sort that iterates itself every time I build my project, and that I can output by my program.

So for example, when generating audio, I need to add metadata that states that this audio file was generated by build #1551. After I build again, that number should go to #1552.

What is the proper way to do this in Qt?

Comment: Unless you have a way to track build numbers back to the version of the source code used for the build this is rather useless, no? Instead of a build number you'd better use e.g. the git commit SHA. Anyway Qt doesn't have much to do with this, you need to setup your build system to, for example, create a header file containing the unique number before compilation starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proper way is:

- Have (any possible) Version Control in your project (and forever for all projects)
- Instead of rather useless autoincremented counter use *any id*, provided by VCS of choice
- [Get this id and output it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550071/qt-automatically-adding-version-for-application) (Mercurial sample, another SCMs just use another commands in `$$system` call)as any other variable